# Duplicate Blog ID in array

Tags: php

I have two tables first one is tbl_blogs that contains all the blog categories such as, men, women etc.

The second table contains the blog's information of related category.

```
 $query1=mysqli_query($link,"select * from tbl_blog_cat");
    $array1=array();
    $array2=array();
    $rows=array();
    $row=array();
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($link)){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){

        $catId=$row['id'];
        $catName=$row['title'];

        $q2=mysqli_query($link,"select * from tbl_blogs where 
           blog_cat=$catId");
        if(mysqli_affected_rows($link)){

            while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($q2)){

                    $rows['BlogId']=$row2['BlogId'];
                    $rows['Title']=$row2['Title'];
                    $rows['blog_cat']=$row2['blog_cat'];

                   $rows['Description']=$row2['Description'];

                  $rows['CoverImage']=$row2['CoverImage'];
                    array_push($array1,$rows);

            }

            $array2[$catName]=$array1;

        }


    }
    echo json_encode($array2);
     }
```

-----------------    here is my output -------------------

The second array of women category has a duplicate id of the previous category. 
I'm expecting to remove or it let me know if there is any mistake in my code.

thanks.`enter code here`

```
  { "Men": [ { "BlogId": "25", "Title": "layer", "blog_cat": "5", "Description": "a sheet, quantity, or thickness of material, typically one of several, covering a surface or body", "CoverImage": "Screenshot_from_2018-12-28_23-12-51.png" } ], "Women": [ { "BlogId": "25", "Title": "layer", "blog_cat": "5", "Description": "a sheet, quantity, or thickness of material, typically one of several, covering a surface or body", "CoverImage": "Screenshot_from_2018-12-28_23-12-51.png" }, { "BlogId": "19", "Title": "Blog Test Man", "blog_cat": "6", "Description": "no dsc", "CoverImage": "Screenshot_from_2019-01-07_16-54-44.png" }, { "BlogId": "22", "Title": "layer", "blog_cat": "6", "Description": "a sheet, quantity, or thickness of material, typically one of several, covering a surface or body", "CoverImage": "Screenshot_from_2018-12-28_23-12-51.png" }, { "BlogId": "24", "Title": "Blog Test Man", "blog_cat": "6", "Description": "no dsc", "CoverImage": "Screenshot_from_2019-01-07_16-54-44.png" } ] }
```

Comment: You should give your variables more descriptive names.

Comment: This is pretty unclear. Can you show your table rows and your expected output? We may remove duplicate IDs from the array but it's trivial to do it with PHP if we could sort this out by SQL itself. Also, depending upon your design, duplicate IDs may not be a wrong output.

Comment: _“or it let me know if there is any mistake in my code“_ - database queries inside loops are considered a rather bad thing in general; you should maybe rather properly JOIN this data together in a single query in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep populating `$array1`, but you don't clear it when you start a new category.

Try putting `$array1=array();` after your first `while`